# Pulseaudio setting up sinks and sources for A2DP and HFP connections

Tags: pulseaudio, alsa, bluetooth, bluez

I'm trying to set up A2DP+HFP profiles in an embedded board. Goal is to use pulseaudio 12.2, ofono 1.18, and bluez 5.41 in order to connect to a mobile phone and use A2DP, HFP profiles automatically, whenever necessary. I did lots and lots of things to update the versions and configure the daemons. Right now I can see that HFP profile is available when connected.

A2DP works perfectly and I am able to stream music from phone to embedded board. When I get a call, I can answer it with Bluetooth and it looks that HFP is the active profile whilst I'm in the call. The weird thing is that there is no audio from the embedded board (HDMI monitor connected to it).

The following will give you how it looks like. When I'm streaming music from phone via A2DP, I get following sources and sinks:

```
pactl list short sinks
0   alsa_output.hw_1_0  module-alsa-sink.c  s16le 2ch 48000Hz   SUSPENDED
1   alsa_output.platform-sound.analog-mono  module-alsa-card.c  s16le 1ch 48000Hz   SUSPENDED
2   alsa_output.platform-sound-hdmi.stereo-fallback module-alsa-card.c  s16le 2ch 48000Hz   RUNNING

pactl list short sources
0   alsa_output.hw_1_0.monitor  module-alsa-sink.c  s16le 2ch 48000Hz   SUSPENDED
1   alsa_output.platform-sound.analog-mono.monitor  module-alsa-card.c  s16le 1ch 48000Hz   SUSPENDED
2   alsa_input.platform-sound.analog-mono   module-alsa-card.c  s16le 1ch 48000Hz   SUSPENDED
3   alsa_output.platform-sound-hdmi.stereo-fallback.monitor module-alsa-card.c  s16le 2ch 48000Hz   IDLE
5   bluez_source.D8_5B_2A_5B_7B_E6.a2dp_source  module-bluez5-device.c  s16le 2ch 44100Hz   RUNNING
```

Whenever I'm in the call (using HFP), I get following sources and sinks:

```
pactl list short sources
0   alsa_output.hw_1_0.monitor  module-alsa-sink.c  s16le 2ch 48000Hz   SUSPENDED
1   alsa_output.platform-sound.analog-mono.monitor  module-alsa-card.c  s16le 1ch 48000Hz   SUSPENDED
2   alsa_input.platform-sound.analog-mono   module-alsa-card.c  s16le 1ch 48000Hz   SUSPENDED
3   alsa_output.platform-sound-hdmi.stereo-fallback.monitor module-alsa-card.c  s16le 2ch 48000Hz   SUSPENDED
7   bluez_sink.D8_5B_2A_5B_7B_E6.headset_audio_gateway.monitor  module-bluez5-device.c  s16le 1ch 8000Hz    IDLE
8   bluez_source.D8_5B_2A_5B_7B_E6.headset_audio_gateway    module-bluez5-device.c  s16le 1ch 8000Hz    RUNNING

pactl list short sinks  
0   alsa_output.hw_1_0  module-alsa-sink.c  s16le 2ch 48000Hz   SUSPENDED
1   alsa_output.platform-sound.analog-mono  module-alsa-card.c  s16le 1ch 48000Hz   SUSPENDED
2   alsa_output.platform-sound-hdmi.stereo-fallback module-alsa-card.c  s16le 2ch 48000Hz   SUSPENDED
3   bluez_sink.D8_5B_2A_5B_7B_E6.headset_audio_gateway  module-bluez5-device.c  s16le 1ch 8000Hz    RUNNING
```

This is quite weird since sink changes from my HDMI monitor to the bluetooth device itself whenever I am in the call. Please find my `/etc/pulse/default.pa` below:

```
.fail

### Automatically restore the volume of streams and devices
load-module module-device-restore
load-module module-stream-restore
load-module module-card-restore

### Automatically augment property information from .desktop files
### stored in /usr/share/application
load-module module-augment-properties

### Should be after module-*-restore but before module-*-detect
load-module module-switch-on-port-available

### Load audio drivers statically
### (it's probably better to not load these drivers manually, but instead
### use module-udev-detect -- see below -- for doing this automatically)
load-module module-alsa-sink device=hw:1,0
#load-module module-alsa-source 
#load-module module-oss device="/dev/dsp" sink_name=output source_name=input
#load-module module-oss-mmap device="/dev/dsp" sink_name=output source_name=input
#load-module module-null-sink
#load-module module-pipe-sink

### Automatically load driver modules depending on the hardware available
.ifexists module-udev-detect.so
load-module module-udev-detect
.else
### Use the static hardware detection module (for systems that lack udev support)
load-module module-detect
.endif

### Automatically connect sink and source if JACK server is present
.ifexists module-jackdbus-detect.so
.nofail
load-module module-jackdbus-detect channels=2
.fail
.endif

### Automatically load driver modules for Bluetooth hardware
.ifexists module-bluetooth-policy.so
load-module module-bluetooth-policy ag=true auto_switch=2
.endif

.ifexists module-bluetooth-discover.so
load-module module-bluetooth-discover headset=auto
.endif

### Load several protocols
.ifexists module-esound-protocol-unix.so
load-module module-esound-protocol-unix
.endif
load-module module-native-protocol-unix auth-anonymous=1

### Network access (may be configured with paprefs, so leave this commented
### here if you plan to use paprefs)
#load-module module-esound-protocol-tcp
#load-module module-native-protocol-tcp
#load-module module-zeroconf-publish

### Load the RTP receiver module (also configured via paprefs, see above)
#load-module module-rtp-recv

### Load the RTP sender module (also configured via paprefs, see above)
#load-module module-null-sink sink_name=rtp format=s16be channels=2 rate=44100 sink_properties="device.description='RTP Multicast Sink'"
#load-module module-rtp-send source=rtp.monitor


### Load additional modules from GConf settings. This can be configured with the paprefs tool.
### Please keep in mind that the modules configured by paprefs might conflict with manually
### loaded modules.
.ifexists module-gconf.so
.nofail
load-module module-gconf
.fail
.endif

### Automatically restore the default sink/source when changed by the user
### during runtime
### NOTE: This should be loaded as early as possible so that subsequent modules
### that look up the default sink/source get the right value
load-module module-default-device-restore

### Automatically move streams to the default sink if the sink they are
### connected to dies, similar for sources
load-module module-rescue-streams

### Make sure we always have a sink around, even if it is a null sink.
load-module module-always-sink

### Honour intended role device property
load-module module-intended-roles

### Automatically suspend sinks/sources that become idle for too long
load-module module-suspend-on-idle

### If autoexit on idle is enabled we want to make sure we only quit
### when no local session needs us anymore.
.ifexists module-console-kit.so
load-module module-console-kit
.endif
.ifexists module-systemd-login.so
load-module module-systemd-login
.endif

### Enable positioned event sounds
load-module module-position-event-sounds

### Cork music/video streams when a phone stream is active
load-module module-role-cork

### Modules to allow autoloading of filters (such as echo cancellation)
### on demand. module-filter-heuristics tries to determine what filters
### make sense, and module-filter-apply does the heavy-lifting of
### loading modules and rerouting streams.
load-module module-filter-heuristics
load-module module-filter-apply

load-module module-switch-on-connect

### Make some devices default
# Make HDMI default
set-default-sink 0
#set-default-source input
```

The following is my `.asoundrc` ALSA configuration (HDMI device by default):

```
pcm.!default {
    type hw
    card 1
    device 0
}
```

Comment: Also for me, Linux Mint 19 with Blueman app and pulseaudio. I paired Moto C Plus via bluetooth and I can listen to music from phone, but when calling it becomes mute...

Comment: Same issues here. I tried with Ubuntu 18.04 on UDOO Neo (iMX6, BT provided by TI WL18XX). A2DP works with minor crackling. HFP sound is mute (even if the amplitude is graphed on pavucontrol). `pactl list` shows the correct routes (they automatically change when switching A2DP/HFP). I gave up!

Comment: @Francesco Hi, I somehow managed to do this, I hope it can help you too. In default.pa or system.pa -depending on which mode you use the pulseaudio with-, use set-default-source <source-name> and set-default-sink <sink-name> below the file. Also comment load-module module-switch-on-port-available and 
load-module module-switch-on-connect. This was the only setup it worked for me, but it does not allow hot-plugging. So you'll have to set one source for mic and one sink for speaker, thats it.

Comment: Please don't [crosspost](https://superuser.com/questions/1357839/pulseaudio-setting-up-sinks-and-sources-for-a2dp-and-hfp-connections). I've voted to close the other question (and leave this one up), because I think U/L is a better match for this question.